# toFixed no me funciona al recorrer un json

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy intentando recorrer un objeto json mediante un for y mostrarlo en una tabla, el problema es que hay unos de los items que tiene muchos decimales, y quisiera mostrar solo dos utilizando toFixed(2) pero no muestra el numero completo.

```
  for(var i = 0; i < clientes.data.length; i++){        
      $("#lista").append(`  
        <!--card 1 -->
        <div class="card`+i+`">
<div id="card" >
    <img id="foto" src="`+clientes.data[i].FotoPartido+`" alt="coche">
    <div id="parrafo">
        <P class="nombreCandidato">`+clientes.data[i].NombrePartido+`</P>

    
         <P class="nombrePorcentaje"><span class="por">`+clientes.data[i].PorcentajePartido+`%</span> `+clientes.data[i].VotosTotales.toFixed(2)+` Votos</P></div>
         <div style="padding-left:  5px; grid-column:   x1;"> <div class="container">
        <div class="skill html" style="background-color:`+clientes.data[i].ColorPartido+`"></div></div>
    </div>  
</div></div>
        
`);
  };
```

clientes.data[i].PorcentajePartido.toFixed(2) es el que tiene muchos decimales.

Comment: ¿Que te muestra?

Comment: En el codigo que enseñas no existe `clientes.data[i].PorcentajePartido.toFixed(2)`.

Comment: claro, y como lo tendría que implementar?

Comment: @JonathanOrta me muestra el numero entero, con todos los decimales

Comment: Creo que lo estas confundiendo con `clientes.data[i].PorcentajePartido` ya que no tiene el toFixed, quien lo tiene es VotosTotales